# Form docks in Panel only on second try

Tags: vb.net, user-interface, panel

I am fiddling around with panels to enhance my skills with GUIs :) I found a strange problem and can't find a solution.

I have a form with one button and two panels. In the left panel there is only a button. The right panel should show a form in itself when the button is clicked. The right panels property "dock" is set to "fill" so the right part of the main form is always filled with said panel.

[image: Pic 1]

Now I am trying to load a simple form with blue background in the right panel. The form ("TestForm") should always fill the right panel ("TestPanel"). Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TestPanel.Controls.Clear()
        TestForm.TopLevel = False
        TestForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TestPanel.Controls.Add(TestForm)
        TestForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        TestForm.Refresh()
        TestPanel.Refresh()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What happens is, when I click the button, the form is loaded inside the panel as supposed:
[image: Pic 2]

But when I resize the main form, the form in the right panel is not filling it up:
[image: Pic 3]

If I hit the button a second time, it works:
[image: Pic 4]

I don't understand why I have to click the button a second time.

I fiddled around with the properties of the TestForm and the TestPanel and also tried adjusting the order of loading the TestForm-Control in the TestPanel. But I always ended up having to click the button twice.

Comment: If you copy the code inside the click handler and paste it again, so the sequence runs twice, does it work?

Comment: @djv That's funny. Yes, it works. But I don't understand why.

Comment: @djv it works with that code:
   `Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TestPanel.Controls.Clear()
        TestForm.TopLevel = False
        TestForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        TestForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        TestForm.Parent = TestPanel
        TestPanel.Controls.Add(TestForm)
        TestForm.Show()
        TestPanel.Controls.Clear()
        TestPanel.Controls.Add(TestForm)
        TestForm.Show()
    End Sub`

Comment: Remove commands until it doesn't work. Then you know which one you need twice. Find the minimal code you need. Report back

Comment: @djv After TestForm.Show() I have to call `TestPanel.Controls.Clear()` and then `TestPanel.Controls.Add(TestForm)` 
`TestForm.Show()`
If I do it that way it works. But it doesn't make sense to add the form, show the form, then delete the form and add the form again.
Sorry for the bad formatting, but I can't figure out code blocks in the comments

Comment: Works fine for me, with the default instance, without clearing the panel and also without the Resize() event. I only need to click the button once and the blue form fills the right side as I resize the form.

Comment: @JimPanseKing you can edit your question with the new code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the [default form instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/development-with-my/default-object-instances-provided-by-my-forms-and-my-webservices). Instead, declare an instance of the form Class, just as you would do with any class, and add that to the Panel:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TestPanel.Controls.Clear()
    TestPanel.Controls.Add(New TestForm)
End Sub
```

Then, in the constructor of `TestForm`, assign the Form's properties to allow it to be added to the Panel:

```
Public Class TestForm

    Public Sub New()
    
        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        TopLevel = False
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Visible = True

    End Sub

End Class
```